# Checking a relation of a prolog list element

Tags: list, prolog

Lets say I have a relations

```
Happy(james)
Happy(harry)
unhappy(Tom)
unhappy(Ben)
unhappy(Dick)
```

And then a list of people

`[Ben, James, Harry, Tom, Dick]`

How can I iterate the list and check the boolean of each list element as to whether they are happy or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, in Prolog, if a word starts with a capital letter, it means that it is a variable. So you should be careful with that.

This is my database after the correction:

```
happy(james).
happy(harry).
unhappy(tom).
unhappy(ben).
unhappy(dick).
```

and I added a recursive rule that helps me see who is happy and who is not from a given list:

```
emotion([]).
emotion([H|T]):- happy(H),emotion(T),
                 write(H),write(' is happy.'),
                 nl;
                 unhappy(H),emotion(T),
                 write(H),write(' is unhappy.'),
                 nl.
```

Here is the result:

```
4 ?- emotion([ben, james, harry, tom, dick]).
dick is unhappy.
tom is unhappy.
harry is happy.
james is happy.
ben is unhappy.
true.
```

Comment: Thank you this has helped alot, am struggling as a beginner

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to dealing with this task. This answer doesn't fuss with with IO, which is unnecessary here, and it goes into some detail about the strategy employed:

I'm working with the following facts:

```
happy(james).
happy(harry).
unhappy(tom).
unhappy(ben).
unhappy(dick).

people([ben, james, harry, tom, dick]).
```

Your desired end can be achieved with a simple predicate establishing a relationship between a name and the `happy/1` and `unhappy/1` predicates:

```
person_happiness(Person, happy(Person))   :- happy(Person).
person_happiness(Person, unhappy(Person)) :- unhappy(Person).
```

This `person_happiness/2` exploits the homoiconic nature of Prolog. The instance of `happy/1` appearing in the rule's body is a call to the predicate, and it is true just in case `Person` can be unified in a call to the fact `happy/1`. The instance of `happy/1` occurring in the second argument of `person_happiness/2` functions as a data structure, and essentially works to label `Person` as happy. This second argument could be replaced with `happy-Person`, `happy/Person`, `happy=Person`, `emotion(Person, happy)`, and many other things besides.

With this predicate alone, we can generate a report of all the happy and unhappy people by backtracking over free variables:

```
?- person_happiness(Person, Happiness).
Person = james,
Happiness = happy(james) ;
Person = harry,
Happiness = happy(harry) ;
Person = tom,
Happiness = unhappy(tom) ;
Person = ben,
Happiness = unhappy(ben) ;
Person = dick,
Happiness = unhappy(dick).
```

We can also find the Happiness for a particular person:

```
?- person_happiness(dick, Happiness).
Happiness = unhappy(dick).
```

And we can find all the people who share a common quality:

```
?- person_happiness(Person, happy(Person)).
Person = james ;
Person = harry.
```

The queries above work just by consulting the facts `happy/1` and `unhappy/2`, but you want to check these facts against the names in your list. We can use `member/2` in conjunction with `person_happiness/2` to achieve everything you want with backtracking:

```
?- people(Ps), member(P, Ps), person_happiness(P, PH).
Ps = [ben, james, harry, tom, dick],
P = ben,
PH = unhappy(ben) ;
Ps = [ben, james, harry, tom, dick],
P = james,
PH = happy(james) ;
Ps = [ben, james, harry, tom, dick],
P = harry,
PH = happy(harry) ;
Ps = [ben, james, harry, tom, dick],
P = tom,
PH = unhappy(tom) ;
Ps = [ben, james, harry, tom, dick],
P = dick,
PH = unhappy(dick).
```

To get all of these results in one go, we can use `maplist/3` to apply `person_happiness/2` to each member of the `People` in `people(People)`:

```
?- people(People), maplist(person_happiness, People, PeopleHappiness).
People = [ben, james, harry, tom, dick],
PeopleHappiness = [unhappy(ben), happy(james), happy(harry), unhappy(tom), unhappy(dick)]
```