# In prolog way to check a list of relations of list elements

Tags: list, prolog

I am new to prolog,

I am having trouble accessing relations of list elements I have checked here - [Checking a relation of a prolog list element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040825/checking-a-relation-of-a-prolog-list-element) 
but I feel as though it doesn't fully answer my question.

I have the relation for a owning a car i.e. you need money and a job to have a car

```
vehicle(car).
own(car, [money, job]).
```

Then I have a list that is like

```
[[money, job], [car]]
```

I wanted to check the list to see if `money` and `job` exist before having a `car` element.

So for example if I was to have something like

```
test([[money, job], [car]]).
OUTPUT: true
```

However If it was

```
test([[job], [car]]).
OUTPUT : false
```

Since money is not present

So my question is, is it possible to check a list elements list of list relations to see if a list element can exist considering the requirements and if not, what is the best approach to handling something like this?

EDIT : I wanted to be able to test a bunch of things for example

```
 vehicle(truck).
 own(truck, [money, job]).

 own(motorbike, [money, job]).
 thing(money).
 own(job, [suit]).
 vehicle(car).
 own(car, [money, job]).

 List of lists : test([[suit], [money, job] , [car, truck, motorbike]]) : True
                 test([[money, job] , [car, truck, motorbike]]) : False since you can't have job without money
                 test([[suit], [job] , [car], [truck], [motorbike]]) :False because you can't have car without owning money, same for truck and motorbike - but will fail on car
                  test([[car], [suit] , [money, job]]): False, because you can't have car without money or job which is after it.
```

See where I am coming from?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to check if every element from some list appears in the other list. You can use `intersection\3` to do it (and there are many other ways):

```
test(Want, Have) :-
    own(Want, Need),
    intersection(Need, Have, Need).
```

Test run (signature is different from what you provided, but I think this make more sense and also yours has syntactic errors):

```
?- test(car, [money, job]).
true.

?- test(car, [job, money]).
true.

?- test(car, [job]).
false.

?- test(car, [money, strength]).
false.

?- test(car, [money, strength, job]).
true.
```

Comment: I made an edit, what you have shown seems redundent, I mayaswell just run own(want, need). For example I mayaswell instead of make a  test for it, I would get the same answers above just going own(car, [job]).

Comment: @Sim but `own(car, [money, strength, job])` will fail, as well as `own(car, [job, money])`. My `test` predicate will success in such cases/

Comment: @SerygeyDymchenko Ah yeah I see waht you mean...not quite what I was hoping to accomplish however